# How to return list of members in a specific voice channel in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I am working on a command that moves a random member of a specific voice channel, but when it creates the list of members, it gives the error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'members'" to the code below. How do I create a list of member in a specific voice channel?

```
@client.command(aliases=['prison'])
async def move_member(ctx):
    voice_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, id='670006903815929893')
    user = random.choice(voice_channel.members)
    await client.move_member(user, name='Jail')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All discord.py ids are integers, not strings:

```
@client.command(aliases=['prison'])
async def move_member(ctx):
    voice_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, id=670006903815929893)
    user = random.choice(voice_channel.members)
    jail = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name='Jail')
    await user.edit(voice_channel=jail)
```